# How to get difference one of array from other array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have :

```js
mncs: [ [ 0 ], [ 3 ], [ 5 ], [ 90 ] ],
upMncs: [ [ 0 ], [ 3 ], [ 90 ] ],

criteria.mncs
criteria.upMncs
```

I need to get **addMncs: [ [ 5 ] ],** to cut same elements from first array and get unlike
I use lodash
Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `difference` after `flatten`:

```
var criteria =  {
mncs: [ [ 0 ], [ 3 ], [ 5 ], [ 90 ] ],
upMncs: [ [ 0 ], [ 3 ], [ 90 ] ],
}
console.log(_.difference(_.flatten(criteria.mncs), _.flatten(criteria.upMncs))) 
// [5]
```